# Node returning error - "route is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm brand new to node and just running through a tutorial I found. I punched in the code as written, which as I understand ought to be importing the route function from the router file. However, the server encounters an error on trying to load the page returning the error in the title.

Here is my code:

```
// index.js; my main file I run through cmd
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router")

server.start(router.route);
```

```
// router.js; the route function is stored here
function route(pathname) {
    console.log("About to rout request for " + pathname);
}

exports.route = route;
```

```
// server.js; the meat
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start() {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received");

        route(pathname);

        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        response.write("Hello World!");
        response.end();
    }   

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

While I'm asking, can anyone explain how the server.start(router.route) line is working? I thought that start function didn't take arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While I'm asking, can anyone explain how the server.start(router.route) line is working? I thought that start function didn't take arguments.

^ That's why it isn't working.

`route` is undefined in the start function. Change the start function to:

`function start(route) { ...`

Comment: That'd do it! Thanks. Again, I'm just following along a tutorial so I'm pretty new, but is that the only way to do it? Could you not just import route in the start function as needed?